# Can't compute the value of Resistance of Operational Transconductance Amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, resistance, ota, transconductance-amplifier

I have the following Operational Transconductance Amplifier that I need to implement in LTSpice. I need to choose a value for \$R_2\$ and \$C_{inf}\$ in order to have a (theoretical)gain value \$A_v=1500\$.

What I found is that:

\$I_{C5}=I_{C6}=I_{C7}=I_{C8}=(V_{cc} - V_{be})/R_2\$;

\$I_{C1}=I_{C2} = (I_{C7} / 2 ) \cdot  (\beta /(\beta+1))\$; \$I_{C4}=I_{C2}-I_{C5}\$;

\$I_{C3}=I_{C1}-I_{C3}-I_{C4}\$;

β in my case it's ~180 because I'm using an BC847A transistor.
\$A=V_o/V_g = g_{m_{_{Q2}}} \cdot  \beta_{q5} \cdot  R_1\$
\$g_{m_{_{Q2}}}=I_{C2} / V_t\$ that it's aprox \$40\cdot I_{C2}\$.

I need to implement the following circuit in LTSpice but I don't know if my schematic is ok and what values \$C_{inf}\$ and \$R_2\$ should be.

The following constraints are imposed:

- \$V_{CC}=10V\$
- \$V_{CM} = 1.5V\$
- \$R_1= 15k\Omega\$
- \$Vg\$ is  a  sine  wave  with  a  frequency  of  1  kHz, whose amplitude  will  be  chosen  so  as  to ensure minimal distortion of the output signal (i.e. \$v_0\$ should also be a sine wave);

The first picture is the schematic and the second one the LTSpice implementation.

Did I did something wrong here?
[image]
[image]

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? Like I mentioned there, you need to do the small signal analysis. I suggest you take a couple of steps back. Start with a common emitter circuit and do small signal analysis on that one. I see you messing with \$\beta\$ and that tells me you're quite unfamiliar with the method you need to apply here to get to the solution.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie And with what should I ,,mess" if it's the only info that I get?Do you have a much simpler solution for this problem?

Comment: There is no "much simpler". To someone with experience it is all quite simple, just draw the small signal equivalent circuit and in a few steps you have an expression for the small signal gain. **Learning how to do that** is the hard part and cannot be explained "in a simple way". You're asking for shortcuts where there are none. What have **you** done to learn how to do small signal analysis?

Answer (score 1):

> *I need to implement the following circuit in LTSpice but I don't know
>   if my schematic is ok*

and...

> *Did I did something wrong here?*

[image]

Comment: Besides that, Vcc it's a power supply...so the schematic it's not ok, right?

Comment: Is there something unclear about my answer that you do not understand? Speak plainly please.